# Choose When & For Each

Tags: xml, xslt

New to the site and xsl so be patient.   Not sure how this post will come out and I'll probably need to upload the actual XML/XSL.

I have an XML with two basic groups.  1 for Gas, 1 for Electric.   Its setup like:

```
   <TS_810>
      <Group_6>
        <IT1>
          <IT107>ELECTRIC</IT107>
        </IT1>
        <GROUP_9>
           +<SLN>
            <SAC>
              <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
              <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>
         </GROUP_9>
         <GROUP_9>
           +<SLN>
            <SAC>
              <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
              <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>
         </GROUP_9>
       </GROUP_6>
       <Group_6>
        <IT1>
          <IT107>GAS</IT107>
        </IT1>
        <GROUP_9>
           +<SLN>
            <SAC>
              <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
              <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>
         </GROUP_9>
         <GROUP_9>
           +<SLN>
            <SAC>
              <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
              <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>
         </GROUP_9>
       </GROUP_6>
```

I am trying to identify the IT107 section for Electric in GROUP_6, then select each GROUP_9 detail line for it.   Once done, then I want to select the IT107 section for Gas in the next GROUP_6 and then select all the detail lines in its related GROUP_9 sections.

The xsl code I have is doing the following.  Note it is not all the code, just the choose/when/for each section.

```
    <xsl: choose>
       <xsl:when tes="GROUP_6/IT1/IT107 = 'ELECTRIC'">
          <xsl:for-each select="GROUP_6/GROUP_9/SAC">

         <fo:table-row>
           <xsl:value-of select="SAC01"/>
         </fo:table-row>
```

What is happening is that I get the detail lines for Electric but I also get the gas section Group_6/Group_9 detail lines.  The Choose group loop doesnt seem to select just the GROUP_6 electric section.

Is there a way to select Group_6/Group_9 lines for ELECTRIC only?  Then I'll create another Choose to select the Group_6/Group_9 lines for GAS.

Or is there a way to look back to value of the IT107 section before selecting the SAC01 details?

Any thoughts?   make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Well when you test if a Group_6 contains 'Electric' it will always return true, because at least one Group_6 has 'Electric' in it.

Then your loop comes too late. A good solution would be to drop the when and use following for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="GROUP_6[IT1/IT107 = 'ELECTRIC']/GROUP_9/SAC">
```

This loop will then enter all GROUP_6 which has 'ELECTRIC'. Make use of the square brackets in which you can post conditions (correct term is [predicates](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp))

Here my input.xml and the test.xslt:

```
<TS_810>
    <Group_6>
        <IT1>
            <IT107>ELECTRIC</IT107>
        </IT1>
        <GROUP_9>
            <SAC>
                <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
                <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>

        </GROUP_9>
        <GROUP_9>
            <SAC>
                <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
                <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>

        </GROUP_9>
    </Group_6>
    <Group_6>
        <IT1>
            <IT107>GAS</IT107>
        </IT1>
        <GROUP_9>
            <SAC>
                <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
                <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>

        </GROUP_9>
        <GROUP_9>
            <SAC>
                <SAC01>DETAILS</SAC01>
                <SAC02>DETAILS2</SAC02>
            </SAC>

        </GROUP_9>
    </Group_6>
</TS_810>
```

The stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/TS_810">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group_6[IT1/IT107 = 'ELECTRIC']/GROUP_9/SAC">
                <SAC><xsl:value-of select="'Electric SAC'"/></SAC>               
        </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives you that output (only two  from the Electric):

```
<root>
    <SAC>Electric SAC</SAC>
    <SAC>Electric SAC</SAC>
</root>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I cannot believe how easy and obvious your suggestion was!  Works perfect.  Thank you VERY much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate when you accept the answer - then I get at least some reputations ;-)